# PS/2 devices stop working in 10.10 release

Tags: 10.10, input-devices

This is a very weird problem. I have Ubuntu 10.10 x64 installed on a machine, and every PS/2 device (more precisely mouse and keyboard) stops working after some minutes.

How can I diagnose this problem?

This is the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DMI (rev 11)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 11)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Management Registers (rev 11)
00:08.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor Semaphore and Scratchpad Registers (rev 11)
00:08.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Control and Status Registers (rev 11)
00:08.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor Miscellaneous Registers (rev 11)
00:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link (rev 11)
00:10.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Routing and Protocol Registers (rev 11)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev 06)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G98 [GeForce 8400 GS] (rev a1)
03:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362/JMB363 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
03:00.1 IDE interface: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362/JMB363 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
07:04.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller (rev c0)
```

... and of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 08ec:0008 M-Systems Flash Disk Pioneers TravelDrive 2C
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and, finally, a `uname -a`:

```
Linux ubuntu-PC 2.6.35-22-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Sun Sep 19 20:32:27 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: you say every PS/2 device; do you have access to USB input devices? Also, can you confirm that the system has not frozen (is the clock still ticking?)

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks for you comment. Yes, I confirm that it happens whenever a PS/2 device is plugged in. I have a USB keyboard plugged in that machine and the problem just happens with the mouse itself (PS/2 connection, instead of USB). Also, the system is still responding, as I can interact with it through ALT+TAB, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You're, most likely, suffering from [a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/557065) which seems to have been around for some time. I was suffering from this bug in Lucid myself, but the upgrade to Maverick fixed it for me.

I have found one possible workaround for me, which made it possible to prevent it from freezing 9 out of 10 times. I simply logged into the Gnome-Failsafe Session directly after boot, waited there for one minute and then I was able to log into my normal session without my PS/2 devices freezing.

In the end it seems to be a problem with X, because I could work on the terminal (tty) normal, but the moment I switched back to the X Session, the devices froze again.

Comment: This problem is also affecting my Fedora 14 X64 installation on the same machine, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with Ubuntu itself.

Bobby, I'll try your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding the following line in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf: "blacklist asus_atk0110".

Comment: @skorzen: Please add this an answer and accept it. I'd also appreciate it if you add this information to the bug report (if not already there).